# Need to pass parameters to ajax file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a web page with a couple of buttons and each button loads information on the page through ajax. Each button calls the same action in controller. That action, called "load" then calls an ajax file which in turns loads different information on the page depending on which button was clicked.

My buttons in my html file look like this.

```
<%= button_to "Load Profile", { :controller => "surveys", :action => "load"} %>
<%= button_to "Load Personality", { :controller => "surveys", :action => "load"} %>
<%= button_to "Load Experience", { :controller => "surveys", :action => "load"} %>
```

The load action in the surveys_controller.rb file looks like

```
def load
  respond_to do |f|     
    f.js { render 'shared/ajax/info.js.erb' }
  end
end
```

The info.js.erb file looks like this

```
$('#email').empty().html("<%= j render(:partial => 'shared/survey/tech/profile') %>")
```

This has worked for me in other places but now the content i need to load differs. I need the "#email" and the "shared/survey/tech/profile" to be a parameter sent from the load action. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Just want to know, why are you using button_to rather than link_tag? and what alias for load action on your routes?

Comment: fyi for set parameter on `button_to` looks like this `<%= button_to "Load Profile", { :controller => "surveys", :action => "load", :parameter => "load-profile" } %>` , read about `button_to` [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to)

Comment: I'm not using button_to any particular reason and my routes looks like get 'surveys/load'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the same action and same js.erb file for each button therefore **you need to send some data using your buttons** in order to differentiate with of the buttons is clicked.

For that you need to follow these steps:

a. **Create a `post` request for your custom method *load***

```
post  'surveys/load' => "surveys#load"
```

b. **Send some data through your buttons which will differentiate them**:

```
<%= button_to "Load Profile", { :controller => "surveys", :action => "load", :profile => "yes"} , :method=>:post, :remote => true  %>
# this will make you access params[:profile]
```

c. **Check inside your load method which button is being clicked using params:**

```
def load
  @profile = params[:profile]
  #other params to store values of personality and experience
  respond_to do |f|      
    f.js { render 'shared/ajax/info.js.erb' }
  end
end
```

d. **Inside your info.js.erb file you could check which one of the variable is equal to yes and then render accordingly**

```
<% if @profile == "yes" %>
  #render your partial
<% elsif @personality == "yes" %>
  #render your partial
<% elseif @experience == "yes" %>
  #render your partial
<% end %>
```

On a second thought i think it'll be better if we just separate out this logic inside controller and depending on the params value render different js files like:

```
def load
  @profile = params[:profile]
  #other params to store values of personality and experience
  if @profile == "yes"
    respond_to do |f|      
      f.js { render 'shared/ajax/profile_info.js.erb' }
    end
  elsif @personality == "yes"
    respond_to do |f|      
      f.js { render 'shared/ajax/personality_info.js.erb' }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @user1612051 like what?

Comment: You gave me an idea. Can i do something like this

<%= button_to "Load Profile", { :controller => "surveys", :action => "load", :id => "email", :file=> "shared/survey/tech/profile"} , :method=>:post, :remote => true  %>

the load action turns into

id = params[:id]
file = params[:file]

and then the .js.erb file is
$('#<%= j id%>').empty().html("<%= j render(:partial => '<%= j file%>') %>")

Comment: @user1612051 i think i got the idea what you are trying to do. You could send the file but i don't think there's any need to send an email as it's static and will be same in every case. Need to test it properly though but i think it should work

Comment: @user1612051 Syntax in your js.erb file doesn't look good though. Give a try to this: `$("#email").empty().html("<%=j render(:partial => file) %>");`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this and see if it works for you;

```
<%= link_to "Load Profile", { :controller => "surveys", :action => "load"}, remote: true %>
<%= link_to "Load Personality", { :controller => "surveys", :action => "load"}, remote: true %>
<%= link_to "Load Experience", { :controller => "surveys", :action => "load"}, remote: true %>  

respond_to do |form
    format.js { }
end
```

and then;

```
$('#email').empty().html("<%= j render(:partial => 'shared/survey/tech/profile') %>")
```